# Combining map layer with onclick function

Tags: dojo

Given this API
http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=map_explicitlayerlist

I would like to add the onclick function for adding layers.

This example does not work because there is only 1 base map and the layers will be shared by all basemaps (if created in the future).

What I am looking for is having multiple basemaps and ONLY 1 basemap will have an option for adding layers by the user and NOT be available in other basemaps.

```
function createBasemapGallery() {

    //manually create basemaps to add to basemap gallery
    var basemaps = [];
    var firstBasemapLayer = new esri.dijit.BasemapLayer({
        url:""
    });
    var firstBasemap = new esri.dijit.Basemap({
        layers:[firstBasemapLayer],
        title:"Imagery",
        thumbnailUrl:"http://i.imgur.com/Un0r0ts.png"
    });
    basemaps.push(firstBasemap);

    var secondBasemapLayer = new esri.dijit.BasemapLayer({
        url:""
    });
    var secondBasemap = new esri.dijit.Basemap({
        layers:[secondBasemapLayer],
        title:"Airports",
        thumbnailUrl:""
    });
    basemaps.push(secondBasemap);
}
```

This creates different map layers and I want an onclick function where if the user clicks on a basemap, an option of layers pop up for just that basemap and disappears when clicking a different basemap.

Comment: well, so basically you want to have a basemap switch, and based on the active basemap you want to show/hide the buttons for the dynamic layers control is that correct?

Comment: Alex, I don't think anyone here will be willing to write the code for you, but basically what you have to do is to:
 - create a background-layer switch (selectbox or whatever)
 - listen to the onchange event and based on the value, show hide the controls AND layers you don't want to see. 
It's not a rocket science. If you still need an assistance, post more code or create a basic jsfiddle or plunker or similar

Comment: Yes I understand. So I would do the
 
dojo.connect(obj, event, context, method) 

where it listens to an action and does something. I would be listening to when a certain layer is clicked to activate the show/hide control. The obj and event would from the createBasemapGallery function. 

Referencing the above code it would look something like this?
dojo.connect(createBasemapGallery(), "firstBasemapLayer", context, method)

If I were to put this in Java, the obj and event would be the if statement and the context and method would be the then? So if an object is clicked, then this will happen?

Comment: what's confusing here is the "trigger" point. I imagine that to switch between layers, you'd have a button or dropdown or some other control, that would switch between the layers. So you'd be listening to the "onChange" event of this control, so dojo.connect(control, "change", callback). within a callback you'd detect to which layer the user is about to switch so you'd show/hide whatever you need. hope that helps